# Gulp and babel are extremely slow

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation, command-line-interface, babeljs, gulp-babel

I'm having issues with gulp and to a greater extent, babel, running extremely slow. It literally takes 2-4 minutes to process 3 javascript files. Even when I just run `gulp` it seems to take at least 10 seconds to start up, not sure why.

Here are the relevent parts of my gulpfile.js...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $    = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js', 
    'bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js', 
    'js/owl.carousel.min.js'])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015']
  }))
  .pipe(concat('plugins.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

And this is my package.json file...

```js
{
  "name": "foundation-sites-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Basic template for a new Foundation for Sites project.",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping": "^6.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.12.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp sass"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues",
    "email": "foundation@zurb.com"
  },
  "author": "ZURB <foundation@zurb.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

After running `gulp scripts` it take 4 minutes!...

```
[15:41:47] Using gulpfile /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/wp-content/themes/example/gulpfile.js
[15:41:47] Starting 'scripts'...
[15:43:55] Finished 'scripts' after 4.13 min
```

Any ideas why this is so slow? I'm fairly new to npm and gulp so I'm not really sure what to do. I have another Foundation project set up on my home computer and it compiles js almost instantly. So I definitely have something screwed up on this machine.

Comment: Are you using `npm@2` or `npm@3`? If you're using v2, you probably need to `npm dedupe`.

Comment: Using 2.5. I think I might have found the problem. Coda was trying to index all of the node_modules files for searching and I think that was slowing everything down. I stopped that process and it seems to be working a lot faster now.

Comment: Can you provide this as answer and accept it?